# nodejs on Vagrant - can't load the page from outside

Tags: node.js, networking, vagrant

Trying to load http://localhost:3000 in browser doesn't work from my windows machine, but when I do this

```
curl -v http://localhost:3000
```

on my vagrant VM - page loads fine.

I was thinking about port forwarding issue, so I set

```
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 3000, host: 3000
```

in vagrant config file, but it doesn't help.

I've tried to capture calls to port 3000 on my vm, like this

```
sudo tcpdump -i eth0 'port 3000'
```

This indicates that vagrant VM can hear my calls to it, but nodemon doesn't know about it.

I'm stuck here, any advice appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: did you run `vagrant reload` after adding the port forwarding directive? Also check `iptables` isn't blocking you (`iptables -L`)

Comment: m1keil, thanks so much, problem was on iptables. I did "iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 3000 -j ACCEPT", which solved the issue

Answer (score 7, accepted):

thank you [m1keil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2944584/m1keil)!

I did `sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 3000 -j ACCEPT` and it solved the problem