# Can't access a node express app from vagrant host machine

Tags: node.js, networking, express, ports

I am new to networking and assigning ports and things of that nature. I have been using vagrant for some time and have never had any problems trying to get a test environment up and then accessing it through the host machine browser. The set up for this in my Vagrantfile is this:

```
# network stuff
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8000, host: 8000
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
config.vm.hostname = "test-box-debian"
```

Now I am trying to learn a bit about node.js, and every tutorial says I can run `npm start` and indeed this works fine. I can call `wget localhost:3000` (port 3000 being the default in express) and in return get the `index.html` default page from express.

However when I try and access `192.168.33.10:3000' from the host browser, it doesn't work. I can run netstat and get the following as a result:

```
sudo netstat -ltpn | grep 3000
tcp6       0      0 :::3000                 :::*                         LISTEN      17238/node
```

I can see that something doesn't look right but I just don't know enough about ports and networking to know what is wrong and how to fix it.

Answer (score 6):

First, ensure your server is listening to the right IP and that you haven't bound the Express listener elsewhere:

`.listen(3000)`, NOT `.listen(3000, '127.0.0.1')`

Alternatively, try binding the Express server to your private IP or to the wildcard IP and see if that resolves your connectivity issues:

```
// Wildcard (All IP's) binding
  .listen(3000, '0.0.0.0')

// Specific binding
  .listen(3000, '192.168.33.10')
```

Lastly, port 3000 may not be accessible from the host. If none of the above options in your server code work, try adding the following line to your Vagrantfile:

`config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3000, host: 3000`

Comment: None of these did the trick. I might try and launch a new box and see what happens.

Comment: You're the man! This worked! Now I won't have to kill myself!

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you don't have a firewall on your VM blocking the port:

`sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 3000 -j ACCEPT`

Found the answer over at https://stackoverflow.com/a/28474080/1772120.

Answer (score 1):

If your vagrant setting is like

```
# network stuff
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8000, host: 8000
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
config.vm.hostname = "test-box-debian"
```

Then your node app should listen to 192.168.33.10:8000

```
const http = require('http');

const hostname = '192.168.33.10';
const port = 8000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
 res.statusCode = 200;
 res.setHeader('Content-Type','text/plain');
 res.end('Hello World\n');
})


server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
 console.log('Server running at');
})
```

Comment: This did the trick for me. I'm currently running a dev server based on https://github.com/rattfieldnz/Vaprobash/, although looking into Docker more.